# Правильно ли я понимаю задание?

Tags: c++, c

Привет, я студент, заканчиваю первый курс.
Дали 10 заданий, очень простых, но одно я не совсем понимаю.

> В заданный непустой текст входят только цифры и буквы. Определить, удовлетворяет ли
>   он следующему свойству: текст является десятичной записью числа, кратного 9.

Я должен работать с элементами строки, как с числами?
Т.е. если "123", то это 1, 2, 3?
Если да, то как?

Зная, что с char можно работать, как с int, я сделал вот так:

```
int if_div_by_9 (char str[], int n)
{
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        num = num * 10;
        num = num + str[i];
    }

    if ((num % 9) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Но при этом "1" в строке не будет 1. Я так понимаю, будет использоваться код ASCII. 
Если нужно работать именно с числами из строки, то как быть с буквами?
Я бы мог написать функцию, которая бы возвращала указатель на новый массив, в котором уже нет букв, но я все еще не знаю, как работать с числами, а не с их кодом.
И я не уверен, что понимаю условие этого наверное школьного задания.

UPD:

```
int if_div_by_9 (char str[], int n)
{
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ('0' <= str[i] && str[i] <='9')
        {
            num *= 10;
            num += (str[i] - '0');
        }
    }
    cout << num << endl;
    if ((num % 9) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 1. Проверить, что все символы - цифры (std::isdigit), 2. Если сумма цифр делится без остатка на 9, то число кратно 9.

Comment: Чтобы преобразовать ASCII символ в число, надо из кода символа вычесть '0' (код нуля).

Comment: Я бы добавил: либо `int if_div_by_9(...) { ... return 0; }` (С-код), либо `bool if_div_by_9(...) { ... return false; }` (C++ код). Ну и 'D' - '0' == D (если D - цифра) - требование стандарта С (С++), т.е. не зависит от кодировки.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вариант решения (если довести его до ума), не будет работать с числами, которые длиннее 9-10 знаков. Разумеется, преподаватель введёт строку гораздо большего размера. Пусть ваша строка имеет размер `n` символов. Вам нужно пройтись по ней и убедиться, что все символы - это цифры. Проверить, что `c` - это цифра можно условием `'0'<=c && c<='9'`. Далее можно сложить значения всех цифр. Либо, как написали вам выше в комментариях, отнимать от значения каждого символа `'0'`, либо просто сложить все символы и затем один раз вычесть `n*'0'`. Как известно, признак делимости на 9 - сумма цифр делится на 9. То есть полученную сумму и нужно проверять на делимость на 9.

В одном вы правы - задание это школьное, 5-й класс, если измерять по нашей школе (дополнительные занятия по информатике для продвинутых детей). Я очень озадачен видеть подобное в вузе... хотя, сейчас уже всё возможно.

Comment: Проверка на цифры делается при помощи `isdigit()`. Не надо велосипедов со сравнениями.